# I need to increment something in order to show the next image in a query

Tags: asp.net, image, visual-studio-2010

I have a Datalist element that I'm trying to make as a table with 3 cells. I want each cell to show a different image. Here's the what I've got so far:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="DataList1"
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" 
    DataKeyField="ID">

    <ItemStyle></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="5,10,5,10">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" BorderWidth="1px" Width="230px" Height="180px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" BorderWidth="1px" Width="230px" Height="180px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image3" BorderWidth="1px" Width="230px" Height="180px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

So it make sense that when I run this, the same picture shows on the entire first row, but what I need to have is a different picture in each cell. As a bonus, also when I run this, it puts all three cells in a table and then creates a different table, breaking the borders. I need to figure out how to get it to not do that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Or can the GridView control handle this better?

Comment: What are you binding the DataList to?

Comment: @chappoo I believe the answer to your question is an Access database.

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I'm more interested in the actual data schema you're binding to.  I'll take a guess at how to help in a follow up answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the RepeatColumns and RepeatDirection properties

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/showing-multiple-records-per-row-with-the-datalist-control-vb

Comment: OMG! That was awesomely easy and easier than I was making it! Thank you so much!